# Importing data from scanned text into Django as YAML fixture or SQL

Tags: python, django, fixture

I'm setting up a simple Django app -- a quiz. The questions and answers come from printed sample tests that have been scanned, OCR'd and parsed. I've parsed them into Python objects like so:

```
class Quiz(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.questions = {}
class Question(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.answers = {}
class Answer(object):
    def __init__(self, text, value= -1.0, explanation=""):
        self.text = text
        self.value = value
        self.explanation = explanation
```

but my Django models, being unable to have "lists" as model fields use foreign keys to keep the relationship between quiz-

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(quiz)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.TextField()
class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(question)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    text = models.TextField()
    explanation = models.TextField()
    value = models.FloatField()
```

Could someone suggest a straightforward way to go from the former to the latter? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to directly create a Question model instance as I parse the source text. The problem is that when I try to import my models, `from models import Choice, Question` I get the following error:
`File "...quiz/printparser.py", line 22, in <module>
    from models import Choice, Question
  File "...quiz/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Question(models.Model):
  File "...django/db/models/base.py", line 52, in __new__
    kwargs = {"app_label": model_module.__name__.split('.')[-2]}
IndexError: list index out of range`
Does Django have limits beyond normal Python imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question to ask yourself is why you are using these intermediate classes at all?  This sounds like bad design.

Once we move past the bad design.  Your code shows that qustion.answers is a dictionary not a list, I assume you just made a typo.

If you have a Quiz model instance you can call `Quiz.question_set.all()` to get all questions for that quiz.  The result of this call will be a queryset, which is an iterable object and as such calling `list(Quiz.question_set.all())` will give you a list.

I can't emphasize enough though that you're doing it wrong and should most likely just be doing away with the middleman.  Also PEP8 naming rules are very much a good idea to follow, ie classes are named like so:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    ...
```

It will make your life easier to follow the conventions =)

Comment: First, yes, "list" was a typo. I was referring to the lack of a collections field type, list, dict, set, etc. in Django. Second, you're right about the naming convention. Thanks for the reminder to follow the PEP. Finally, I'm using the _bad design_ because I cannot determine how to directly get the OCR'd text into Django directly. It seems that I was unclear about the fact that I need to get large amounts of data into Django's DB, not out -- that I can manage.

Comment: Show me an example of what your are storing in an answers dict and I can show you how to map it to your models.  I would expect a quiz to have multiple questions so I would expect it wild be represented by a list, or a list of dicts, but not a dict directly.  Though I should note if this is a large amount of data and you'll be doing it regularly you're going to want to find a MUCH different way of doing it, bulk importing data through django's ORM is slow and very painful